# Address Additions and Multiplications in C

Tags: c, memory-management

Is there a way of adding two memory addresses or multiplying a memory address with a number, in C?

If so, how? For example let's say I have address:

```
void * p = (void *) 0x80000000;
```

And I want to multiply by 2 or add another address, to change current address of the variable!

Comment: Type cast can work, but its meaning less, also `sizeof(int)` may not = `sizeof(void*)` on some platform

Comment: `(void *) 0x80000000` is most likely *not* an address.

Comment: The problem you describe in a comment to one of the answers, managing memory and dividing an area of memory into parts, does not require adding addresses or multiplying an address by a number. It only requires adding integers to (or subtracting integers from) addresses and ordinary arithmetic on the integers (not the addresses).

Comment: thanks guys! I did solve the problem with unwind's example, changed intptr_t to uint32_t as you mention Eric....!;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `0x28ff44` is not the "address of the variable" `p`, it's merely the value of the variable. Since the variable is a pointer, the value is an address. You can certainly modify the value *as if* it were an integer, by converting to/from integer, but why would you ever want to do that?

Here's a silly function to double the value of a pointer:

```
void * double_address(void *p)
{
   const intptr_t pi = (intptr_t) p;

   return (void *) 2 * pi;
}
```

Comment: what about 0x80000000? without conversion is not possible?

Comment: @feruz No, without conversion, you can only add integers to pointers (or subtract integers or pointers from pointers) - within narrow confines. But since there is no known reasonable use for multiplying pointers or adding pointers to pointers, it hasn't been missed so far.

Comment: An address is a pointer value that points to an object, but not all pointer values are addresses. `void *foo = 0;` The value of foo is not an address because it doesn't point to an object.

Comment: @unwind thanks for the example, I have changed intptr_t to uint32_t and manage to get it work! Thanks to everyone for prompt replies! cheers

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *meaningfully*<sup>*</sup> add two addresses together in C, or multiply an address by a number or another address. The two operations that are allowed are subtracting addresses that point to a contiguous block of memory, and adding a positive or a negative integer to an address. Multiplying or adding two addresses together does not make sense, because the result does not produce a meaningful address.

---

<sup>*</sup> Think about it this way: since addresses are just numbers, and because math lets you multiply and add numbers freely, does not mean that the result of the mathematical operation would produce anything meaningful. For example, you can certainly add the length of an airport runway, in inches, to the capacity of the fuel tanks of an airplane, in gallons. You would get a number as a result of this strange calculation, but it would remain just a sequence of digits, devoid of any meaning in the physical world.

Comment: Thinking about it that way isn't necessarily helpful. "The Symbolics Lisp Machine, a tagged architecture, does not even have conventional numeric pointers; it uses the pair <NIL, 0> (basically a nonexistent <object, offset> handle) as a C null pointer." -- http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Comment: @modifiablelvalue The handle of `<NIL, 0>` is ultimately represented as *some* meaningless number internally. Once you obtain that number, you can multiply it by anything that fits on the screen of your calculator, and get a sequence of digits out of it. It is needless to say that the new sequence of digits would be as meaningless as the original one has been.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'm aware you can do is add an integer value to a pointer and this will cause the pointer to move along in memory `sizeof(pointertype)`.

Example:

```
int* ptr;
int arr[2];
//put some values in arr;
ptr = &arr[0];
ptr = ptr + 1; // will cause the pointer to move along in the array by `sizeof(int)`
```

Adding or multiplying addresses in any other way I've never heard of or seen.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what are you trying to do ?

You can copy the variable to another pointer, then set to set the first variable.

```
// Creates new pointer with new address (why ?)
void* new_var_ptr = malloc( <size_of_p> );

// Copy content of "p" address to "new_var_ptr" address
memcpy( new_var_ptr, p, <size_of_p> );

// Set "p" content to NULL (optional)
memset( p, 0, <size_of_p> );

// Set "p" to NULL (optional)
p = NULL
```

Then "new_var_ptr" will points to the previous content of p.

Comment: well I am trying to manage memory, choosing/sliding into some parts! And I have beginning of address and length. I thought I could start from beginning and then divide equal parts and add next piece.. I hope you got the idea?!

Answer (score 0):

Adding two addresses in C is not valid, and most likely never anything you want to do. You may want to add an OFFSET from one pointer to another, e.g. :

```
 char *ptr1 = ...;
 char *ptr2 = ...;   
 ptrdiff_t d = ptr1 - ptr2;
 char *ptr3 = ptr2 + d;
```

[Note that the above is only officially valid if `ptr1` and `ptr2` points to "the same object" - that is, the same allocation or the same array or similar]

Multiplying a pointer by another pointer would be even more pointless [pardon the pun!]. Since pointers tend to be rather large numbers, the product of multiplying two pointers is also likely to overflow the result, making it even more useless.